# Read TextAsset from StreamingAssets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am reading an excel file that is located in "Resources" folder of my Unity application. I now want to load the same file from different location, i.e. StreamingAssets. Now there is no StreamingAssets.Load(), so how do I load and convert the file to TextAsset?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
public class CSVReader
{
    static string SPLIT_RE = @",(?=(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))";
    static string LINE_SPLIT_RE = @"\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r";
    static char[] TRIM_CHARS = { '\"' };
 
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> Read(string file)
    {
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        TextAsset data = Resources.Load(file) as TextAsset;
 
        var lines = Regex.Split(data.text, LINE_SPLIT_RE);
 
        if (lines.Length <= 1) return list;
 
        var header = Regex.Split(lines[0], SPLIT_RE);
        for (var i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
 
            var values = Regex.Split(lines[i], SPLIT_RE);
            if (values.Length == 0 || values[0] == "") continue;
 
            var entry = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            for (var j = 0; j < header.Length && j < values.Length; j++)
            {
                string value = values[j];
                value = value.TrimStart(TRIM_CHARS).TrimEnd(TRIM_CHARS).Replace("\\", "");
                object finalvalue = value;
                int n;
                float f;
                if (int.TryParse(value, out n))
                {
                    finalvalue = n;
                }
                else if (float.TryParse(value, out f))
                {
                    finalvalue = f;
                }
                entry[header[j]] = finalvalue;
            }
            list.Add(entry);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

and my LoadExcel is as :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadExcel : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LoadItemData();
    }

    public void LoadItemData(){

        //Read csv
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> data = CSVReader.Read("MyExcel");

    }

}
```

I know the way to load file from StreamingAssets and I am changing both the files this way

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> Read(string data)
    {
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var lines = Regex.Split(data, LINE_SPLIT_RE);
 
....
....
```

and

```
string path = Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyExcel.csv");
        UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(path);
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
 
List<Dictionary<string, object>> data = CSVReader.Read(uwr.downloadHandler.text);
```

But it is not able to read. It says "ID" not found, which is the attribute in my CSV column.

Comment: Just use `File.ReadAllText()` to open your file at the streaming assets path and read its content. No need for web requests or anything like that.

Comment: @Bart it is useful if the app is running on a web server so i would like to use WebRequest.

Comment: as an alternative why not stick to an actual `TextAsset` and place it anywhere else but streaming assets and eference it directly in the Inspector `public TextAsset textAsset;`? I don't see why you need it to convert to a `TextAsset` .. simply get the `string` (no matter if using System.IO or Webrequest) and pass it in directly into your parser

Comment: @derHugo I wanted to place it in StreamingAssets because I could then change the file contents even after the app is built.

Comment: @Yidi fair enough! Could you show your entire code you are trying to use? Just to make sure you are e.g. waiting for the request to finish before trying to read ;) Otherwise the best we can tell you would be set breakpoints and debug at which point the code stops to behave as expected

Comment: @derHugo i posted it as my answer as I used the suggestion from Bart.

Comment: @Yidi this won't work on Android but that is probably no your target platform anyway for now ;) Note that also on WebGL I'm not sure if you can simply FileIO into StreamingAssets .. see [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) `To read streaming Assets on platforms like Android and WebGL, where you cannot access streaming Asset files directly, use UnityWebRequest. For an example, see Application.streamingAssetsPath.`

Comment: @derHugo yeah 100%, i was initially looking to use WebRequest itself but I am not able to find a solution for it. If you may, could you alter my LoadExcel script to support WebRequest, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe it sounds like you don't really wait for the webrequest to finish.

This should do it

```
public class LoadExcel : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IEnumerator Start ()
    {
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyExcel.csv");

        using(var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(filePath))
        {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if(request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.LogError(request.error);
                yield break;
            }

            var result = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;

            var data = CSVReader.Read (result);

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give it a try with WebRequest, but instead I just did it with ReadAllText. You could also try with StreamReader I guess but I haven't implemented it that way.

Here is the code for LoadExcel file:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadExcel : MonoBehaviour {

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {
        LoadItemData();
    }


    public void LoadItemData(){

        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyExcel.csv");
        string result;

        result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText (filePath);

        //Read csv
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> data = CSVReader.Read (result);

    }

}
```

and my CSVReader:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
public class CSVReader
{
    static string SPLIT_RE = @",(?=(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))";
    static string LINE_SPLIT_RE = @"\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r";
    static char[] TRIM_CHARS = { '\"' };
 
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> Read(string data)
    {
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        //TextAsset data = Resources.Load(file) as TextAsset;
 
        var lines = Regex.Split(data, LINE_SPLIT_RE);
 
        if (lines.Length <= 1) return list;
 
        var header = Regex.Split(lines[0], SPLIT_RE);
        for (var i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
 
            var values = Regex.Split(lines[i], SPLIT_RE);
            if (values.Length == 0 || values[0] == "") continue;
 
            var entry = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            for (var j = 0; j < header.Length && j < values.Length; j++)
            {
                string value = values[j];
                value = value.TrimStart(TRIM_CHARS).TrimEnd(TRIM_CHARS).Replace("\\", "");
                object finalvalue = value;
                int n;
                float f;
                if (int.TryParse(value, out n))
                {
                    finalvalue = n;
                }
                else if (float.TryParse(value, out f))
                {
                    finalvalue = f;
                }
                entry[header[j]] = finalvalue;
            }
            list.Add(entry);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```